# Make a body bounce inside the screen

Tags: android, box2d, andengine

I'm a full newbie with 2d and physics engines, I want to make a body bounce insice a screen (like the classic windows screensaver).

When the body reaches the left or right side of the screen reverse it X velocity and the same for the top/bottom sides and the Y velocity.

I also need check collisions with other bodies so I can't just move a sprite along the screen

How can I implement this behaviour? I'm using Andengine with the Box2D extension

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For this you have to create a simple circle body as per you attached sprite that you can found in basics Andengine Examples.

Then you have to apply continuous velocity to a targeted body. How to do this stuff you can found in the following link. [Continuous Movement of Object](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/29276/continuous-movement-of-gun-bullet)

And for checking collision with other object you have to use physics contact listener.

Also without using box2d it is also become possible in Andengine. Using Physics Handler you can move your object with desire velocity.